# Cannot send screenshots taken by a method of Robot class from the client to the server

Tags: java

I was able to send a picture from the client to the server using the following code but when I tried to send a screenshot taken by createScreenapture() method, I was able to take the screenshot and save it in my PC but was unable so send it to the server. Could anyone help me please?

These lines capture the screenshot and save it in my PC

```
Robot robot = new Robot(gdev);
this.bImage = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\JAVA\\SocketProgrammingForReal\\Screencapture.jpg"));
```

These are responsible for sending the image

```
public void SendImage() throws IOException {
    ByteOutputStream byteOutput = new ByteOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", byteOutput);
    byte[] size = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(byteOutput.size()).array();
    dout.write(size);
    ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", byteOutput);
    dout.write(byteOutput.toByteArray());
    dout.flush();
}
```

code for receiving the image and for saving it in my PC

```
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
byte[] b = new byte[4];
din.read(b);
int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(b).asIntBuffer().get();
byte[] bImage = new byte[size];
din.readFully(bImage);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bImage));
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\JAVA\\screencapture2.jpg"));
```